# Appending td to table

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue appending another row to my existing table.

```
$('.vv div:first-child').on('click', function(){
 $("tbody").append("<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td><td><span class="hdv dsp">Product</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">1</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp">Price</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$00.00</span></td></tr>");
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. I tried the code above to no avail.

This is the table I am trying to attach it to: https://jsfiddle.net/nwqmvo36/14/

Comment: The repeated double-quotes within the `append()` content is causing a syntax error. You need to escape your double quotes, or use single quotes for `append()`. e.g., `$("#tbody").append(' ... ');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/nwqmvo36/15/

First, this is a problem

```
.append("<tr><td><input type="checkbox"
```

The issue is that your quotes are now no longer lining up correctly. It is best in these situations to use the alternative `'`, like so:

```
.append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" ... all that other html ... ');
```

In addition, you forget to reference `$` (jQuery) in your jsFiddle. Please always check your console for errors as these should have been rather straightforward to address.